# ASP.NET regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have the following Regex

```
(?<!<[title|h1|a][^>]*>[^<]*)(?<!<[meta|img][^>]*[^/>])(someword)
```

I am basically using the above to replace certain words with a url. i.e.

```
The all new product x
```

will become

```
The all new <a href="/productx">product x</a>
```

Its all working as expected. I am doing the negative look behind so I don't replace things which are in tilte, h1 and anchor tags. I now need to extend this so that if there is a bold tag within an anchor tag then it does not match.i.e.

```
<a href="/something">The all new <b>product x</b></a>
```

should not be replaced. The way I have it now the negative lookbehind finds a bold tag and matches. I only want it to skip if the  is inside an . For those who are interested I need this as my search page returns results as

```
<a href="/something"><b>searchterm</b> some other text</a>
```

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't write a good, single regular expression to do what you want. There will always be special cases that will cause false positives. There are better ways to do what you want. That being said, if you're still going for a regex solution, this might be closer to what you want:

```
(?<!<(?:title|h1|a)[^>]*>(?:[^<]|<[^/]|</(?!title|h1|a))*|<[meta|img][^>]*)(someword)
```

Comment: That did work, thanks. Just out of interest what other ways would you suggest? I'm very interested in finding out. Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with what's available in ASP, but if the html you're parsing is valid XML, then you should be able to use `XmlNode` to traverse the document tree. If the node is an element node and it's not a title/h1/a tag, then look at it's children. If it's a text node, then search for the words you want to find. Then you can skip over the elements you don't want to touch, you don't have to worry about matching inside a tag (like the img/meta checks you do), and it's easy to add new tags/conditions to check for.